# Selecting List item in a website using Powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm looking to select a list item (3M) given in the attached image from a website using powershell. I've tried below but no luck .Please suggest
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDEWz.png)

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate2('https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-insider-trading')
while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
$dropdown = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('dayslisting')
($dropdown | where {$_.innerHTML -like "3M"}).Selected = $true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were really close with your solution. This code worked for me. I put comments inline to explain the couple changes I made.

```bsh
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate2('https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-insider-trading')
while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
$dropdown = $ie.Document.body.getElementsByClassName('dayslisting') # You needed to select .body here to use getElementsByClassName
$3m = ($dropdown[0].all | where {$_.innerHTML -like "3M"}) # Dropdown is a list because classes can be assigned to more than one element. I'm getting all elements of the first list, but you could do something better if you wanted.
$3m.click() # Click the "3M" button.
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code can also help to click on the **3M** option on the list.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate2('https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-insider-trading')
while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
$dropdown = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('dayslisting')

$link = $ie.Document.links | Where-Object {$_.outerText -eq '3M'} 
$link.click()
```